# How to display all db items on a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, axios, jsx

I want to retrive all items from the database then **display** users on a **table**

Users should be displayed like this: [image]

I can display just the current user and here is my code :

```
const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/";

class AuthService {

  getCurrentUser() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));;
  }
const currentUser = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
```

[image]

```
                        <TableBody>
                            {this.state.users.map(row => (
                                <TableRow key={row.id}>
                                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                        {currentUser.id}
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="right">{currentUser.username}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="right">{currentUser.email}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="right">{currentUser.roles}</TableCell>
    
                                </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your data is already loaded and you need to pass that data into your react component. I'd recommend to stick to functional components nowadays, since via hooks you can write the same logic as in class based components.

```
function MyTableComponent(props) {
  return (
    <TableBody>
      {props.users.map(user => (
        <TableRow key={row.id}>
           <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
              {user.id}
           </TableCell>
           <TableCell align="right">{user.username}</TableCell>
           <TableCell align="right">{user.email}</TableCell>
           <TableCell align="right">{user.roles}</TableCell>

         </TableRow>
       )}
    </TableBody>
  )}
```

Then you can use that component in your template and pass the props like so:

```
<MyTableComponent users={myUsersArray} />
```